# How to make the javascript variable remove new lines in this case?

Tags: jquery

When i am extratcing the text , it is coming as

```
Orange juice fresh wth topping and crustig provided,and it will be an extracost,.
            juice available for sugar free person also
```

How to make the text come into a single line (remove all new lines )

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/32/

Comment: please fix that fiddle it's a disaster, and the console is not returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace method:

```
str = str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
```

OR

```
str = str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, ' ');
```